# Get formatted text with Selenium Webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Extracting the text from the following HTML code, with getText() method, is not working as I expected.

HTML

```
  <pre id="responseCommand"><code>RP/ABCDEFGHI/
    1.TESTING/UI
    2 PHONE NUMBER
    3 SOME FREE TEXT</code></pre>
```

Java code, in order to extract the text from code tag, is the following:

```
WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement recoverText = waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("pre[id='responseCommand'] code"))); 
recoverText= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("pre[id='responseCommand'] code"));
String textStr = recoverText.getText();
System.out.println("Text extracted: \n" + textStr );
```

The output of the println is the following:

```
Text extracted:
RP/ABCDEFGHI/
1.TESTING/UI
```

The rest, "2 PHONE NUMBER" and "3 SOME FREE TEXT" are not displayed.

*The text is read line by line from a .txt file, and after each read line, sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) is used. That's why, the text in the code tag is displayed on multiple lines.

Despite all the documentation that is available, I could not managed to extract the entire text.

Any thoughts?

Cheers!

Comment: Is the missing text is visible?

Comment: It's probably because at the time you call getText(), the last lines were not yet added. Try to check with native call: js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", recoverText)

Comment: I very much doubt the so-called formatting is the cause of the problem. Is there a page we can test this on?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `innerText` attribute

```
WebElement recoverText = waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("pre[id='responseCommand'] code")));
String textStr = recoverText.getAttribute("innerText");
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found why I only have half of the text displayed. Apparently, each time I am doing a keys.ENTER, a new

```
<pre id="responseCommand">
```

is created, wraped into a div tag.
So, for the first TESTING/UI line entered

```
<div class="textResponse0">
  <pre id="responseCommand">
    <code>RP/NCE1A0955/
     1.TESTING/UI</code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

for the second line PHONE NUMBER entered,

```
<div class="textResponse1">
  <pre id="responseCommand">
    <code>RP/NCE1A0955/
     1.TESTING/UI
     2 PHONE NUMBER</code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

and so on...

My getText() is applied only on the first pre tag. Hence the absence of the other lines.

I did not have discovered this without your comments (inneHTML opened my eyes)

Thank you very much